# mintinline command not compiling with pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, minted

Whenever I try to use the `mintinline` command in a source file and then compile that file with `pdflatex`, I get an error. Minimum example to show the error is provided below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\mintinline{vala}{main}
\end{document}
```

When I run `pdflatex --shell-escape sample.tex` (where `sample.tex`) is the name of the file I have this code in), I get the following output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
\write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./sample.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/catchfile.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)) (./sample.w18)) /usr/bin/pygmentize

(./sample.aux) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (./sample.pyg)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \mintinline
               {vala}{main}
?
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The command is `\mint`, not `\mintinline`. It should be `\mint{vala}|main|` (assuming `vala` is a legal language name).

Comment: @egreg: Quoting the documentation: "Note that the ``\mint`` command is not for inline use. Rather, it is a shortcut for ``minted`` when only a single line of code is present. The ``mintinline`` command is provided for inline use."

Comment: I see no mention of `\mintinline` in the documentation of `minted`. Are you perhaps looking at the manual for the development version?

Comment: Ah, yeah, you're probably right. I took it from the github page for minted, and that's probably the cause. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\mintinline` command is provided by the development version of `minted`, not the one in the current TeX distributions. If you want to use it, manually install the development version.

You can instead use `pythontex`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}
Abc \pygment{vala}|main| def
\end{document}
```

This requires running `pythontex <filename>` after a LaTeX run (when there are new code snippets).

[image]